# NgxHateoasClient - Basic Configuration on Angular

Tags: angular, angular16

I want to use NgxHateoasClient in my angular application. The basic configuration for NgxHateoasClient work is to add the below code in app module of the application -

```
import { NgxHateoasClientModule } from '@lagoshny/ngx-hateoas-client';

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
    NgxHateoasClientModule.forRoot()
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
  ...
}
```

and

```
export class AppModule {

  constructor(hateoasConfig: NgxHateoasClientConfigurationService) {
    hateoasConfig.configure({
      http: {
        rootUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1'
      }
    });
  }

}
```

The problem here is that in my application, there are no modules and all components including the app.component are standalone components. I need some pointers on where to add the above code.

Thanks.